# Lose bottom border colour when I click anyway on page HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a html element where I switch tabs. When I click on the tab, the focus works perfect in terms of highlighting the background colour white and the bottom border is white.

But when I click anyway on the screen, the selected tab's bottom border returns to the default grey border.

What I am trying to do is keep all bottom border of the tabs #999999 except for the selected tab which will have the bottom border white.

How do I not lose the bottom border colour white for the selected tab when I click anyway on screen?

```js
function showPanel() {} // just for suppressing error.
```

```css
.tabContainer .buttonContainer button {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.tabContainer .buttonContainer button:focus {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <button autofocus onclick="showPanel(0)">Course Details</button>
    <button onclick="showPanel(1)">Workshop Schedule</button>
    <button onclick="showPanel(2)">Online Course Details</button>
    <button onclick="showPanel(3)">Online Exam Details</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `showPanel()` is doing, but I assume there you could leverage the event target, and add a class to the element you're interested in, and style accordingly. `:focus` by its very nature does exactly what you're describing, and the style is lost once the element is `blurred`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your example slightly to give an example of what my comment was describing. I've added the button that was clicked as a parameter to the `showPanel()` function, and handled appropriately.

```js
function showPanel(btn, idx) {
  clearActive();
  btn.classList.add('active');
}

function clearActive() {
  const active = document.querySelector('.buttonContainer button.active');

  if (active) {
    active.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.tabContainer .buttonContainer button {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.tabContainer .buttonContainer button.active {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <button autofocus onclick="showPanel(this, 0)">Course Details</button>
    <button onclick="showPanel(this, 1)">Workshop Schedule</button>
    <button onclick="showPanel(this, 2)">Online Course Details</button>
    <button onclick="showPanel(this, 3)">Online Exam Details</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, seems to not be working. Still loses focus when I click off the it

Comment: @BruceyBandit Just to make sure I understand correctly, my snippet isn't working correctly, or am I misunderstanding something?